# Express "if true, then 1 else 0" in a formula suitable for Desmos calculator

Tags: functions, notation, calculator, desmos

In programming, often the value of True is also 1, and False is 0.

This means that:

```
(x>5)*4
```

will return 4 if x is greater than 5 (because `(x>5)==1`), else 0.

I need to accomplish a similar thing using mathematical operators (no piecewise functions, this has to be typed into Desmos calculator.)

Specifically, I need
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 1&&\text{if}~ x\leq n \\ 0&&\text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
without having to use piecewise notation. Here $n$ is a positive integer, as is $x$.

Comment: What kind of calculator are you using?

Comment: Is $x$ assumed to be an integer? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @JimmyK4542 desmos.com

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(Posted by [Dave Radcliffe](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1590064) but then deleted):

> The Desmos calculator supports piecewise functions such as `{x<5 : 0, 1}` or `{x<=5 : 0, 1}`

Comment: Are you saying $sign(0) = 1$? If not, then your answer doesn't work.

Comment: very nice........+1

Answer (score 12):

$$
x\mapsto \frac{|2n+1-2x| + (2n+1-2x)}{2|2n+1-2x|} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x\le n, \\ 0 & \text{if } x>n. \end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 9):

To simplify Hardy's answer, a function I commonly use is
$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{n-x}{2|n-x|}$$ 
If you want to make calculations less taxing by working only with integers during calculations, this is obviously the same as
$$\frac{1+\frac{n-x}{|n-x|}}{2}$$
This solution immediately arises from the fact that $\frac{n-x}{|n-x|}$ is either $1$ when $x<n$ and $-1$ when $x>n$
This is obviously undefined for equality of the two variables, although you can add a factor to the top and bottom to change the undefined point, such as
$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{n-x+1}{2|n-x+1|}$$ 
which is undefined not at equality, but when $x=n+1$
This is not needed however, as Desmos has native support for piecewise functions... see [this](http://support.desmos.com/hc/en-us/articles/203192385-Piecewise) link for an explanation by the Desmos devs